# What are the possible asymptotics of the measure of a parametrised semialgebraic set?

Tags: real-analysis, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider a family of semialgebraic sets $S_t \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ ($t \in [0,1]$) of the form
$$ S_t = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \ : \ p_1(x,t) \geq 0,\ p_2(x,t) \geq 0, \dots, p_m(x,t) \geq 0 \} $$
where $p_i$ are polynomials in $d+1$ variables. What are the possible asymptotic behaviours of the measure of $S_t$ as $t \to 0$?

To avoid complications, let us additionally assume that $S_t \subset [0,1]^d$ (I don't know if this significantly changes the problem). Then, it is not hard to see that $|S_t| \to |S_0|$ as $t \to 0$. If $|S_0| > 0$ (I use $|X|$ to denote the measure of a set $X$) then we simply have $|S_t| = (1 + o(1))|S_0|$, so the question in only interesting if $|S_0| = 0$.

**Example 1.** Let $S_t = \{ x \in [0,1] \ : \  t^p - x^q \geq 0\}$ for some $\alpha > 0$ and $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $|S_t| = t^{p/q}$.

**Example 2.** Let $S_t = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \ : \ xy \leq t \}$. Then a simple computation shows that $|S_t| = t + t\log 1/t$ for $t$ small enough, so $|S_t| = (1+o(1)) t\log 1/t$.

Is it possible to describe the (reasonably small) family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ such that for each family $S_t$ like described above there is some $f \in \mathcal{F}$ with $|S_t| = (1+o(1))f(t)$? I'm hoping that one can take $\mathcal{F} = \{ c t^a \log^b t \ : \ a,b,c > 0,\ b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, but that's probably too optimistic.